# In Git, how do you see and manage commits that aren't in a branch?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

A commit isn't necessarily in a branch, so how do you see and manage these commits? Also, is it possible to look at these commits from gitk?

Thanks a lot!

PS: just to make things clearer, here is an example:

```
git init
git commit
touch toto
git add toto
git commit -a
echo $RANDOM > toto
git commit -a
git checkout f798e54 #checkout initial commit
echo $RANDOM > toto
git commit -a #"untracked commit"
gitk --all
git branch
git log
git checkout master #back on the main branch
gitk --all #untracked commit is lost?
git log
git branch
```

How can I get my "untracked commit" back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This situation is called a [detached HEAD](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#detached-head). Normally tools (such as gitk) won't show you commits that aren't reachable by a symbolic branch name.

To get your commit back, you can use [`git reflog`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) to show a log of all recent activity, including your detached HEAD. When you find it, you can use its commit ID with `git checkout` to get back to it. If you find that it's valuable, you may want to give the branch a name at that point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I've discovered a whole area of git that I didn't know of :)

thanks also to "hacker" for mentioning git fsck.

Comment: You don't need commit ID to get back on branch: `git checkout -b newbranch` would be enough.

Comment: Jakub's suggestion works if you realise that you are on an unnamed branch _right now_. The reflog trick is useful when you realise ten minutes later after going to a named branch.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that you're talking about `git fsck --unreachable`?

Answer (score 2):

`git reflog` will show you a symbolic name like `HEAD@{0}` that you can use to access that otherwise unreachable commit. You could then use `gitk --all HEAD@{0}` to see where it exists in your repository.