# Unaccessible git state

Tags: git, branch, history, commit

And previously, I tried to experiment with my program and then, I feel like going back (checkout) to previous commit. Then, I changed something, committed.. etc..

The question is, How do I go back to the state before I checkout.

I know I could git checkout the-hash,

But I don't know the-hash.
git log only show history until the current state.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [In Git, how do you see and manage commits that aren't in a branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361127/in-git-how-do-you-see-and-manage-commits-that-arent-in-a-branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the output of `git reflog`. Look for the checkout, then do a `git checkout HEAD@{X}` where X is the number that `git reflog` shows on the line after that checkout.